# A book of mystery - Page III

Tags: riddle, rhyme, story, geography

Just as was for solving the first
Page number three had started to burst
With ink to tell you what to do
With the book your Uncle had given to you

> A measurement of six squares
> South from page 2s wheres
> 314.2 of these
> And note the road you are on, please
> Take away his Spanish letter
> This is the operation for your next endeavour

Strange words these, I cannot figure
Maybe words for someone with a brain that is bigger!

Hint 1:

> What measure of length is similar to a shape?

Hint 2:

> It is a simple direction from point A to point B

Hint 3:

> It begins with a 'C'

SHOOVER GOT PAGE 2 (THE ANSWER TO WHICH WAS MCDONALD'S ISLINGTON) AND SOLVE PAGE THREE TO GET A HINT TO SOLVE THE NEXT PAGE.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer *might* be:

> Neville Place

My logic is as follows:

> A measurement of six squares is a cubit. There is no official definition, but generally it is about 2 feet. 314.2 cubits south of McDonald's Islington puts you on Pentonville Rd. Removing the Spanish letter (pe) leaves "ntonville". Stretching, I scan this as "N to Nville", and there is a Neville Place about 5 miles north of McDonald's in Islington.

EDIT: Let me take another shot. I think the answer is:

> The Crafts Council building on Pentonville Rd.

Reasoning:

> Following my previous reasoning, you end the second to last line with the clue "ntonville". Instead of trying to parse this, assume it just means "north". If you actually *go* to the point 314.2 cubits south of McDonald's Islington and face north, the Crafts Council building entrance is right there.

Comment: No, that is not the answer. However, you were right with the cubits

Answer (score 0):

Just some random thoughts:

> Google suggests a cubit is equal to 18 inches. So 314.2 cubits would be equal to 471.3 feet. At about that distance SSE of McDonalds there is a place called Cubitt Artists. Coincidence or not?

Comment: It is just a coincidence

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, as per your hints, the 6 squares to be

> a royal cubit, and taking this to be between 523.5 to 529.2 mm

and keeping in mind the Spanish letter I need to remove

> letra

314.2 of these straight south might bring me to

> Leather Lane or Fetter Lane. From which I'd opt for Fetter Lane as I should remove *his* Spanish letter, not its. And the only *he* I could find from these options who has a bigger brain for certain is Alexander L. Fetter, the physics professor.

Removing the letter leaves me with

> aexnderlfet, or for instance 'next federal'.

Which is where I begin to lose confidence in my solution. It might point at

> the Gibraltar Government Office, 150 Strand.

I'm not convinced, but I consider it worth a try.

However, I still struggle with

> the suspiciously round measure of 314.2 and that we shall find an *operation* rather than a location. Maybe I must engage in a more circular reasoning here.

Comment: Hi guys. If you downvote my answers, please leave some helpful criticism in a comment. I fail to see why my attempt at answering this riddle is worse than the other ones here and I would like to improve. But I need some input for that.